# Check if date are the same

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to write a code that check if the date in the column are the same. The row will be grouped by the ID, so if any date in the group is not the same it gets flagged.

This is my dataframe (code):

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("P40", "P40", "P40", "P40", "P42", "P42"),
                     Date = dmy(c(26072013, 26072013, 2092012, 23082012, 01072014, 01072014))),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The table form:

```
ID       Date
P40     2013-07-26
P40     2013-07-26
P40     2012-09-24
P40     2012-08-23
P42     2014-07-01
P42     2014-07-01
```

This is what i want to achieve:

```
ID    Contsistent
P40      No
P42      Yes
```

Answer (score 4):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(Consistent = factor(n_distinct(Date) == 1, 
            levels = c(FALSE, TRUE), labels = c("No", "Yes")))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  ID    Consistent
#  <chr> <fct>     
#1 P40   No        
#2 P42   Yes
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Consistent = uniqueN(Date) == 1), .(ID)]
#   ID Consistent
#1: P40      FALSE
#2: P42       TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Consistent = c("No", "Yes")[(n_distinct(Date) == 1) + 1])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  ID    Consistent
  <chr> <chr>     
1 P40   No        
2 P42   Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use aggregate from R base for this

```
# Check Date for each ID in df
aggregate(Date ~ ID, data= df, function(ID_i){ 
# if there is only one unique Date value in ID_i then the function gives "Yes", otherwise it gives a "No"
          ifelse(length(unique(ID_i)) == 1, "Yes", "No")})

   ID Date
1 P40 No
2 P42 Yes
```